# Use bat file in CGI Python on localhost

Tags: python, apache, batch-file, cgi

I'm quite stuck with with a complex mix of files and languages! The problem:
My webform starts a python script, as a cgi script, on localhost(apache). In this python script I want to execute a batchfile. This batchfile executes several commands, which i tested thoroughly.

If i execute the following python file in the python interpreter or in CMD it does execute the bat file.
But when I 'start' the python script from the webform it says it did it, but there are no results, so i guess something is wrong with the cgi part of the problem?!

The process is complicated, so if someone has a better way of doing this...pls reply;). I'm using windows so that makes things even more annoying sometimes.

I think it's not the script, because I try `subprocess.call`, `os.startfile` and `os.system` already!
It either does nothing or the webpage keeps loading(endless loop)

Python script:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
p = subprocess.Popen(["test.bat"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = p.communicate()
print out
print "DONE!"
```

The bat file:

```
@echo off
::Preprocess the datasets
CMD /C java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -b -i data_new.arff -o data_new_std.arff -r tweetin.arff -s tweetin_std.arff
:: Make predictions with incoming tweets
CMD /C java weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -T tweetin_std.arff -t data_new_std.arff -p 2 -c first > result.txt
```

Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bat file is redirecting the second program's output to a file, so `p.communicate` can only get the output of the first program. I'm assuming you want to return the content of `result.txt`?

I think you should skip the bat file and just do both java invocations in python. You get more control of the execution and you can check the return codes, there might be problems with `java` not being in the `PATH` environment variable when run as CGI. The following is mostly equivalent with respect to you getting the program's output back, you want to capture the second program's output if your webservice is supposed to return the predictions.

```
import os
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -b -i data_new.arff -o data_new_std.arff -r tweetin.arff -s tweetin_std.arff"), 
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = p.communicate()
return_code = subprocess.call(shlex.split("java weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -T tweetin_std.arff -t data_new_std.arff -p 2 -c first > result.txt"))
print out
print "DONE!"
```

Comment: There are more commands in the bat file. The commands are sequentual, they need files from each. In the end I create a html page with all the results. 

Java not being in PATH is not true, because it is and when I run the bat file in CMD it executes normally.

Can you explain the return_code = ... ect?

Comment: shlex just splits the command line 'intelligently' into an array for Popen.

Comment: and you can call the commands sequentially from within python using `subprocess.call` or `communicate`. You would still have more feedback about error conditions. Also, is the same `PATH` used in your `cmd` and apache's CGI-handler?

Comment: subprocess.call returns 0 on success, something else on error, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: Ok! The code like my code works is you run it in Python Interpreter, but not if I ask to run it as CGI script from my webform, which is on localhost(apache) So isn't it because CGI just can't run bat files??

Comment: I'm sorry, what Path in apache CGI-handler. You mean in httpd.conf file?

Comment: python on windows through CGI should be able to call bat files. Can you make another script that returns `os.environ['PATH']`? That's the path your CGI runs with

Comment: If i run the os.environ in the interpreter or in cmd it gives the same output. Also when i run the script as cgi through the webform

Comment: might mod_python/mod_wsgi/FastCGi work in this case? With these mods you can run cgi scripts(python) as python scripts, right! Because my script and the script in this answer both work in the Python Interpreter!

Comment: No, not when i run it from the form and not when i run it in the Python Interpreter

Comment: you can check if you can run java through CGI by `print subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'])`. How does java find the class to execute? Have you set `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: The java commands work in the Python shell/Python interpreter(whatever you want to call it) but the whole subprocess doesn't work when it's call as a cgi script, or i'm I seeing this wrong?

Comment: subprocess.Popen(['java', '-version']) return None, so this would mean python launches shell(cmd.exe) but can't find the java lib's? Java is in my classpath and if i run java -version in a shell(cmd.exe) it works...

Comment: try `subprocess.check_output` as stated above. And you need some weka.jar` or the like, I assume? Where is that, and is in in `os.environ['CLASSPATH']` if using CGI?

Comment: The location of weka.jar is stated in the CLASSPATH. I print it using CGI. subprocess.check_output still gives me nothing. If i als 'java' '-version' with Popen it works though...

Comment: do you get no output at all with CGI and check_output?

Comment: then try `print subprocess.call(['java', '-version'])`that should result in 0

Comment: Some further testing...i guess you're right, it skips the java commands for some reason. but when I check the commands in cmd.exe they work. Also when run from the python script in python interpreter it works but then in cgi from the form it skips them.

Comment: I tried executing the bat file from the CGI script from the form and it can print 'java -version', commands like 'dir' and 'pwd' but not my complex java weka command...

Comment: have you tried to use full paths for your input and output files?

Comment: I just thought about something...if i run the java weka command normally, it doesn't return anything, which means: "i'm done, the files are created." Desired is that the command says: "i'm done". I tried adding '&ECHO done', but them just displays 'done'. Since it's impossible to make the command print something, my problem is unsolvealbe...?!

Comment: Also fully paths is not the solution...and subprocess.call gives 0!

Comment: You can check if the output file was written to after the process ended: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html 

But I don't think I can offer any more help, sorry

Comment: Do you know what to do when java command is not recognized by CGI...is that a PATH and CLASSPATH problem? What can should i change if the java directory is already in the both environ variables...

Comment: you need the location of you java binary in PATH, the jars with your application and other directories with libraries in CLASSPATH. If subprocess.call('java -version') returns 0, at least that part of PATH is correct.

Comment: To be honest my CLASSPATH and PATH are kind of a mess, but the java bin is forsure in PATH(otherwise i wouldnt be able to execute java commands in cmd.exe). also the weka.jar is in my classpath and can also be accessed by cmd.exe...i can print my path and classpath here but that will make this thread even longer;)

Comment: and won't help, as if both PATH and CLASSPATH are ok, and the input and output file locations are not an issue running on CGI, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: i really appreciate you time!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind. You might want to try setting your Popen's shell=True. Sometimes I have noticed that's solved my problem.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["test.bat"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You may also want to take a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/), which is perfect for this kind of automation.

Comment: I already tried 'shell=True', but when i execute the CGI script from the webform it doens't display a shell window

Comment: Sure, it won't display the shell output directly, it just runs it in a shell-like environment.